# ExtJS: How to store a user's login information only once?

Tags: php, javascript, extjs, authentication

I'm using Ext.Ajax.request() to hit a PHP page that gives me some user specific info as a part of a login process. Basically I want to store some variables (cookie, session information, etc) in ExtJS. I created a model with the needed fields and a store to keep it. Even though the authentication is done only once I want to ensure that on a given time there is only one copy of the user's info. I want to use that info to hit PHP again without having to authenticate again (cookies).
Here's how I fetch it and store it:

```
Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: 'api/get.php',
            params: {
                user : usr,
                pass : pass
            },

            success: function(response)
            {
                var text = response.responseText;
                var jtext = Ext.JSON.decode(text);
                var login = jtext.loginData;

                model.set('username', login.username);
                model.set('cookie', login.cookie);
                model.set('password', login.password); // doing this feels soo wrong!
                store.insert(0, model);
                store.sync();
                console.log(store.getCount());
            }
        });
```

What is the better way of doing it? Since I'm using an external (to the PHP) service currently I only check if the user/pass is correct and if it is, I pass it from the client-side to the PHP functions that do whatever they have to do with the external service, authenticating each time with them. Alternatively I can pass the cookie each time to the PHP that in turn passes it down. I can also map JS<->PHP cookies to PHP<->service cookies and that would be even better.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
Ext.util.Cookies.set('myObj',Ext.encode(obj))
```

Use something like this and when you want to use it

```
id = (Ext.decode(Ext.util.Cookies.get('myObj'))).id
```

Comment: is there a way to put it into the session instead of the cookie?